# Invertibility of the Product of Two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have shown that if two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then $AB$ is also invertible. I am having problems though with showing that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$. I thought of using their left-multiplication transformations but it seems that this is only associative and not commutative so I can reverse $L_A L_B$

Comment: How do you define the inverse of a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The inverse of a matrix $X$ is a matrix $Y$ such that $XY=I$.

Using this, is $B^{-1} A^{-1}$ the inverse of $AB$?

(Note this is assuming that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist)

Comment: should I assume that I know inverse of B and the inverse of A, and when multiplied I get an n x n identity matrix?

Comment: Rather, this only holds if you know the inverse of $B$ and the inverse of $A$. Otherwise the equation just doesn't make sense.