# If $A,B$ are invertible, show that $AB$ is invertible and express $(AB)^{-1}$ in terms of $A^{-1},B^{-1} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A,B$ are invertible, show that $AB$ is invertible and express $(AB)^{-1}$ in terms of $A^{-1},B^{-1} $.
>   $($$A,B$ are matrices.$)$

I did the following: Suppose $AB$ is invertible.

$$AB(AB)^{-1}=I$$

$$A^{-1}AB(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}I$$

$$B(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}$$

$$B^{-1}B(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

$$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

I found what $(AB)^{-1}$ might be, now I need to show that $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ is really the inverse:

$$ABB^{-1}A^{-1}=A[BB^{-1}]A^{-1}=[AA^{-1}]=I$$

$$B^{-1}A^{-1}AB=B^{-1}[A^{-1}A]B=[B^{-1}B]=I$$

1. Is it correct?
2. Do I need these two steps? I feel that the first step shows me what the inverse would be if it exists and the second actually shows that it is the inverse.

**EDIT**: This question is **completely** different of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513432/invertibility-of-the-product-of-two-matrices). In the aforementioned question, the person didnt know **how** to do it. I asked if mine is correct *and* **asked if the first part would be required.** It is sad that MSE users don't read the questions completely anymore.

Comment: The first part is "scratch-work", it describes how you discovered what might work. Only the short second part  should be shown.   For that part, more parentheses would be useful.

Comment: There is a main part which you has not proved it yet!  You need to prove that $AB$ is invertible!

Comment: I agree that the scope of this question is a different one than the mentioned possible duplicate. This one has more proof-checking characteristics.

Comment: @Roland Yes. You ask "How to calculate the determinant and make orange juice with it?" and "How to calculate the determinant?" and people think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a logical fallacy in your argument.  You wish to prove that $AB$ is invertible.  As a result, you may **not** assume that $AB$ is invertible to begin with as this would be circular logic.

Despite this, much of your logic is good, but it could be trimmed down to just your final two lines.

> **Definition:**  An $n\times n$ matrix, $D$, is invertible if and only if there exists a matrix, $E$, such that $DE=ED=I$.  We use the notation $E=D^{-1}$ for short.

So, since $A$ and $B$ are both invertible we know that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist.

As a result, $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})$ exists and $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1}) = A(BB^{-1})A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I$ and thus $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$ by the definition of invertible matrices.

Comment: To completely follow the definition, we must also check $(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)=I$

Comment: @Hagen fair enough, though, if one reads the full invertible matrix theorem, one sees that checking that $DE=I$ is all that is necessary.  For finite $n$, right inverses are always left inverses.  Only when progressing to infinite dimensional spaces does this become an actual issue.

Comment: @JMoravitz I've read a book on fallacies: "Fallacies and argument apraisal". In it, the author argues that we ended up teaching people that *fallacies are bad and must be avoided* but it's actually not that simple because in a deeper study, one can observe that there are situations in which fallacies work, that is, are not actually fallacies. 

I believe the same could be asked on circular logic: Is it always bad? In this case, it helped me yield the correct answer. Is it really a devil that must be avoided at all costs and there are no occasions in which it could be helpful?